# Возможно ли управлять выводом в Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Например так:

```
<div>
ng-if="(message.from == message.to) ? {{friendList[message.from].photo}} : wt.photo"
</div>
```

Comment: Создайте два `<div>` элемента и один показывайте, а другой скрывайте по условию `ng-if`.

Comment: Вы можете создать свою директиву, включив в неё желаемое поведение

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как я указал в комментарии к вопросу, задачу будет проще решить с помощью двух `<div>` элементов с разным содержимым и условием для контроллирования их рендеринга в директиве `ngIf`:

```
<div ng-if="message.from == message.to">{{ friendList[message.from].photo }}</div>
<div ng-if="message.from != message.to">{{ wt.photo }}</div>
```